# (How To:) Using DNS in "Orcus"

Tags: .net, dns

I am working with Orcus since a while now. I wish to avail my clients over the internet. I have a DNS and also a port forwarded. but I don't know how to Build a Client using my DNS.

In the Connections settings do I have to write my DNS under the IP/HOSTNAME TextField? if i do so, how will I have to configure the Server to handle it?

I have used Imminent Monitor too, in their, it clearly states to give IP/DNS in the Connection settings under Build Tab. But I rather have to work with Orcus and I can't find, where should i actually write my DNS, how to configure the serve, etc.

also here, from DNS I mean my DNS address (example:xyz.ddns.net)

(as orcus is a .NET Framework RAT)

Help would be nice.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DNS address is placed in the IP/HOSTNAME field of the connection settings.